# how to display only the elements of a list in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

`(display '(a b c))` returns `(a b c)` but I am looking for a procedure that takes `'(a b c)` as an argument and displays `a b c` instead. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a list of symbols, which has a standard representation: `'(a b c)`. If you want to get rid of the surrounding `()` we have to manipulate the elements as strings, for example:

```
(display              ; finally, display the string
 (string-join         ; join the strings using a space as separator
  (map symbol->string ; convert each symbol to a string
       '(a b c))))    ; this is a list of symbols
```

It'll print:

```
a b c
```